Angle between two tangent of the ellipse when parametric line equation is used
Let $\frac{x}{2} \cos\theta+y \sin\theta=1$ where $\theta \in(\frac{\pi}{18},\frac{\pi}{10})$   intersect the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=6$  at P and Q, then angle between tangent at P and Q is
(A) $\frac{\pi}{16}$
(B) $\frac{\pi}{6}$
(C) $\frac{\pi}{8}$
(D) $\frac{\pi}{2}$
My approach is follow , I tried to substitute the value $\frac{x}{2} \cos\theta+y \sin\theta=1$ in $x^2+2y^2=6$ but not able to get a concrete result.

We have:
$$\frac{x}{2}\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=1\tag1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1\tag2$$
Comparing $(1)$ with the parametric form of tangent equation,
$$\frac{x\cos\theta}{a}+\frac{y\sin\theta}{b}=1$$
We get $$a=2,b=1$$

So this question can be re-framed as
"Let a tangent to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{1}=1$
intersect the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1$ at $P$ and $Q$.
The angle between the tangents at those two points are?"

Now we have two concentric ellipses with $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{1}=1$ being the inner ellipse and $\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1$ being the outer ellipse respectively.
Since the line (1) is tangent to the inner ellipse and goes on to meet the outer ellipse at two points from which a pair of tangents are drawn, the line (1) can be called the chord of contact of the outer ellipse.
What's the equation of chord of contact?
Before this let us denote (h,k) as the point of intersection of the pair of tangents:
let $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ be an ellipse, then the equation of chord of contact is $\frac{hx}{a^2}+\frac{ky}{b^2}=1$
Putting in $a^2=6,b^2=3$,
$$\frac{hx}{6}+\frac{ky}{3}=1\tag3$$
Since (3) is a tangent to the inner ellipse, we can utilize the following result that confirms the tangency of a line ($y=mx+c$) to an ellipse ($\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$):
$$c^2=a^2m^2+b^2$$
Comparing (3) and the inner ellipse we get:
$c=\frac{3}{k}, m=\frac{-h}{2k}, a^2=4, b^2=1$
Plug in the above values and we get:
$$h^2+k^2=9$$
$$x^2+y^2=9$$
Which resembles the equation of a circle, but also the "director circle" of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ which has the equation of director cirlce as $x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2$. On comparing this is the director circle of the outer ellipse(2).
Using the fact that the locus of perpendicular pair of tangents from an ellipse lies on the director circle confirms the angle between the two tangents as $\frac{\pi}{2}$
Option $(D)$ is the answer

